# Retrieving Remote File Share 'Share Permissions' Using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a share hosted on another computer `FILESERVER1` at `\\FILESERVER1\FILESHARE1`.

How do I view the Share Permissions of this folder using PowerShell? Is this possible?

Please note, I am NOT referring to NTFS permissions.

Comment: What attempt(s) have you made so far?

Comment: None. I am looking for a command similar to Get-Acl, but one doesn't appear to exist. It might be the environment I'm in - I may not have access to the 'Get-SmbShareAccess' command - which seems to be more appropriate for this situation.

Comment: Get-acl work just fine...

Comment: @SagePourpre Just to confirm, I am referring to 'Share Permissions' as opposed to 'NTFS' permissions. What is the specific syntax I would have to use?

Comment: So to be more specific: What research have you done so far? (You're not just asking other to do all the work for you, right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get-SmbShare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/get-smbshare?view=win10-ps)  and [Get-SmbShareAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/get-smbshareaccess?view=win10-ps) seem to be what you want, as long as you have PowerShell 5. Those commands are not present on a Windows 7/PSh4 computer I'm using.

You can run the commands on the remote computer by using a session:

```
$s = New-PsSession -ComputerName FILESERVER1
Invoke-Command -Session $s {Get-SmbShare}
Invoke-Command -Session $s {Get-SmbShareAccess 'FILESHARE1'}
```